# Fedora Failed to get D-Bus connection

Tags: mysql, fedora, dbus

I have a VPS with fedora 16 installed. I have setup mysql and it was working a couple of days ago.

Now suddenly when I try to start mysql I get the error:

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Failed to connect to socket /org/freedesktop/systemd1/private: Connection refused
```

I'm not sure when mysql stopped working as I haven't worked with it in a couple of days.
The only software I installed recently was jenkins and redmine.

Comment: So, MySQL isn't running.  What happens when you try to start it?  What's in it's error log?  There is not enough information here for anyone to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: @devicenull I downloaded and installed MySQL from mysql.com, and got it working again. There is however still a problem with systemd, but I am re-doing the entire vps